# Prevent WPF local value coercion behavior

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties, coerce

I created a slider WPF CustomControl and have been surprised about a coercion behavior.

- My Min DP coerces Max & Value
- My Max DP coerces Min & Value

If my Min is 0, My Value 0 and Max is 100, if I change Min to 1 the Value also changes to 1. Ok, that's fine.

Now If I set Min to 0 the Value is changed back to 0.

What's happening is that WPF stores any local value (set by binding, style or programmatically) in a local field but doesn't store a value that has been set by the coerce function.

How can I prevent this behavior?

Comment: Do not use Coercion? Instead CoerceValueCallback use PropertyChangedCallback for everything

Comment: @devhedgehog This would indeed be a simple workaround. I thought maybe this was an option that could be disabled somewhere. Thanks

Comment: if you writing a custom control... customize that b***tch